# Functional (Scala) programming: Split a List[Char] on a token

Tags: scala, recursion, functional-programming, pattern-matching

What is the general accepted implementation of a recursive split-by-token function?

For example:

```scala
val s: List[Char] = 'F' :: 'o' :: 'o' :: ' ' :: 'b' :: 'a' :: 'r' :: ' ' :: 'f' :: 'o':: 'o':: ' ' :: 'b' :: 'a' :: 'r' :: Nil
fooSplit(s) // -> List(List('F','o','o'), List('b', 'a', 'r'), List('f', 'o', 'o'), List('b','a','r'))
```

Here are the base cases I've come up with, when doing pattern matching on the parameter:

```scala
def fooSplit(text: List[Char]): List[List[Char]] = text match {
  case x :: ' ' :: xs =>
    // Somehow append old list to fooSplit(xs) <?>
    println(x + "_")
    fooSplit(xs)

  case x :: xs =>
    println(x + "")
    fooSplit(xs)

  case Nil => Nil
}
```

Most of my attempts following the above structure almost always lead to `List('F', List('O', List('O'), ...)...)`. Without coming up with some very sinister double pattern matching I can't seem to wrap my head on to extend instead of append to the inside list.

---

I would also like to quote the Scala Cookbook:

> Use flatMap in situations where you run map followed by flatten. The specific situation is this:
>
> • You’re using map (or a for/yield expression) to create a new collection from an existing collection.
> • ****The resulting collection is a list of lists.****
> • You call flatten immediately after map (or a for/yield expression)

This seems like a very possible case to use flatMap, could anyone provide insight on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One crucial realization to keep this function from becoming "sinister" is that you can hold the current sublist being built as its own variable, and only add it to the result when it is complete.

From there, it's pretty simple.

There are basically three cases: end of list (done!), current element is space (add intermediate to result, and start with empty again), everything else (just keep adding to intermediate), so you just spell them out:

```
   @tailrec
   def split(
     in: List[Char], 
     next: List[Char] = Nil, 
     out: List[List[Char]] = Nil
   ): List[List[Char]] = in match { 
       case Nil => out.map(_.reverse).reverse
       case ' ' :: tail  => split(tail,  Nil, next :: out)
       case head :: tail => split(tail, head :: next, out)
     }
```

A couple of common tricks here are that you pass the actual result you are building down to the recursive calls, rather than just returning it (that way the function can be optimized as tail-recursive - doesn't need space on stack), and also, you build your lists in reverse direction, prepending elements to them, rather than appending, and then reverse at the end, when the list is complete (this allows implementation to remain linear, because prepending to a list is constant time, unlike append, which is O(N), making the whole thing quadratic (yuck!)).

Answer (score 1):

Just because you're returning an instance of `List[List[String]]` doesn't mean you need to flatten it, sometimes you might need those values. I would suggest this:

```
def fooSplit(text: List[Char]): List[List[Char]] = {
  @tailrec
  def fooSplitHelper(currentListBeforeToken: List[Char] = List.empty, list: List[Char], acc: List[List[Char]] = List.empty): List[List[Char]] = {
    if (list.isEmpty) {
      currentListBeforeToken.reverse :: acc
    } else {
      list.head match {
        case ' ' => fooSplitHelper(List.empty[Char], list.tail, currentListBeforeToken.reverse :: acc)
        case otherChar => fooSplitHelper(otherChar :: currentListBeforeToken, list.tail, acc)
      }
    }
  }
  fooSplitHelper(list = text).reverse
}
```

Comment: Don't append to a `List` is too slow, ather prepend to it and `reverse` at the end.

Comment: @AminMal just think about it (or look at the implementation): how would you append something to the end of linked list. What's the "O-complexity" of that operation?

Comment: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html - https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, @Dima. thanks for your answers. if I wanted to append 5 to [1, 2, 3, 4], I can either append with O(n), or try to reverse the original list (O(n) resulting [4, 3, 2, 1]) and then prepend the value resulting in [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] with O(1)), and then reverse the list again (O(n) resulting in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]). referring to scala docs: `This includes the index-based lookup of elements, length, append and *reverse*`. I have seen other scala developers also try double-reversing, but I can't see any point in it, I also did some code and appending was faster (in most cases)!

Comment: @AminMal sure for a single append is better to do that, but for building a `List` from scratch you build it by appending only and then you reverse that at the end. Which is how any tail-recursive algorithm on a `List` is implemented.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I see, your first comment was like Don't append to a list, I thought what you're saying is that appending is not efficient at any case, but using recursion, of course double-reversing is more efficient, I'll make sure to edit my answer

Comment: During recursion is not even double reversing, is just a single reverse. For example, look at Dima's answer, it could be improved by calling `next.reverse :: out` to avoid the `map(_.reverse)` at the end.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, I did some improvements based on the discussion above, can you please take a look? Also, time complexity of `next.reverse :: out` with reverse at the end, wouldn't differ to `.map(_.reverse).reverse` (I understand that this might differ in action though, but time complexity is the same).

Comment: @AminMal yeah that looks way better :) There is no complexity difference but calling `reverse` during the recursion instead of in a `map` at the end will avoid an unnecessary iteration _(although, technically the `map` and the `reverse` may be combined in a single iteration)_. - Anything else I may have to say is more subjective and fall under the style preferences category, you can see my version here and draw your own conclusions :) https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/vFodyMILQL6EJJt2FUzz5g/2

Comment: @AminMal to be clear, appending to a `List` is pretty much _always_ "bad", it's just sometimes the "badness" can be avoided by the append/reverse trick, and sometimes it can't. If you only need to append something once ever, that's not a real use case. More realistically, you probably have a function, that's called with. arbitrary lists to be appended to occasionally.  You are correct, that would be stupid to reverse inside the function in this case. But it doesn't make appending "efficient". It just means that you are using a wrong data structure for your scenario.